# babel conversion works on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise, babeljs

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm learning JavaScript
I need to use **babel** to convert my ES6 and ESnext codes to ES5. When I do this the final code works on desktop browsers but not on mobile browsers 
I test many ways but they have same results: first online compiler, second offline with npm, webpack, @babel/core, @babel/preset-env, babel-loader and babel-polyfill
The code before use babel:

```
alert('Hello');
let getData = async ()=>{
    const response = await fetch('http://mywebsite/getData.php');
    return await response.json();
};
getData().then((data)=>{
    alert(data['properties'][0]['title']);
    console.log(data['properties'][0]['title']);
});
alert('Goodbye');
```

The code after(with online website):

```
function asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, key, arg) { try { var info = gen[key](arg); var value = info.value; } catch (error) { reject(error); return; } if (info.done) { resolve(value); } else { Promise.resolve(value).then(_next, _throw); } }

function _asyncToGenerator(fn) { return function () { var self = this, args = arguments; return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { var gen = fn.apply(self, args); function _next(value) { asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, "next", value); } function _throw(err) { asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, "throw", err); } _next(undefined); }); }; }

alert('Hello');

var getData = /*#__PURE__*/function () {
  var _ref = _asyncToGenerator( /*#__PURE__*/regeneratorRuntime.mark(function _callee() {
    var response;
    return regeneratorRuntime.wrap(function _callee$(_context) {
      while (1) {
        switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {
          case 0:
            _context.next = 2;
            return fetch('http://mywebsite/getData.php');

          case 2:
            response = _context.sent;
            _context.next = 5;
            return response.json();

          case 5:
            return _context.abrupt("return", _context.sent);

          case 6:
          case "end":
            return _context.stop();
        }
      }
    }, _callee);
  }));

  return function getData() {
    return _ref.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}();

getData().then(function (data) {
  alert(data['properties'][0]['title']);
  console.log(data['properties'][0]['title']);
});
alert('Goodbye');
```

The offline codes are too big and impossible to show you
Do you have any idea?

Comment: What "mobile browser" are you using, and what are the options you passed to `@babel/preset-env`?

Comment: what doesn't work?

Comment: Thank you but I found my problem and it was I worked with a local server so I addressed local addresses like localhost and it didn't work